# Two rounded seekbars overlay each other

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-seekbar

I need to place two rounded seekbars on the same circle area (like on the screenshot). I use SeekArc library. But even if I use only half of the circle for seekbar, view takes the same as full circle. Each SeekBar on the screenshot takes the whole screen and one of them is not active because it's under other one.

If I try to hardcode width then height changes automatically. Is there any way to leave the same height but crop not needed space around widget? Or any other way to place two SeekBard on the circle area?

[image]